# 自然から得られる生産に役立つ要素。 Parsing

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, parsing

> 自然から得られる生産に役立つ要素。

Can someone help me with this?
自然から得られる=You can obtain from nature
生産に役立つ=Useful for production
要素=Components

> 自然から得られる生産に役立つ要素。
>   Components you can obtain from nature which are useful for production.

Is it correct?
So the parsing would not be:
((自然から得られる)>生産に役立つ)>要素。
but
(自然から得られる)--->要素。
(素生産に役立つ)-->要素.
They both refer to 要素.

Comment: (自然から得られる(生産に役立つ要素))。Sorry but I can't see the point of making an anwer just with extra brackets.

Comment: I means: 自然から得られる modifies 生産 not 要素.

Comment: 自然から得られる modifies the whole 生産に役立つ要素 --> Useful elements for production (= 生産に役立つ要素) obtained/gathered from the nature (= 自然から得られる)

Comment: Oh I see, right. I was thinking about single words while i did not think about single clauses.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clause can modify another clause not only a single noun. Here 自然から得られる does not modify only 要素 but 生産に役立つ要素.

`自然から得られる` means `gathered form the nature` (passive and not potential in this context) and `生産に役立つ要素` means useful for production. If you bind them together you get `Elements useful for production gathered from the nature` which is very close to the translation you provided (passive voice instrad of potential form).

Comment: Yeah thanks, I never encountered a clause which modified another clause up until now. I just have to keep reading and develop a "sense" for it or is it there some kind of rule that could make easier to find when one clause modifies another one or when a clause just modifies a noun?

Comment: I would not say that there are clear rules. And it can sometimes be confusing on where to cut, but yes the best the best method is reading extensively to get accustomed.